# best way to communicate between Fragments and Activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity in which I have implemented two fragments, and i have read that implementing interfaces for the fragments in activity is the best approach, but how is it different than passing the activity context in fragment's `view.setOnClickListener()` and then implementing the `onclick` method in activity also i can set the data regarding the click in `view.setTag()` then why should one use an interface? 
Are those both approach same since i am implementing onClick method in activity or different? Also if they are different then how and which one is better?

Comment: Can you please describe with some example I could not get you, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question A [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) and [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData.html) are best for communication.

Read this article for more details

https://android.jlelse.eu/communicate-between-fragments-and-activity-using-livedata-631526d6357a

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot more ways to communicate between activity and fragments. eg. `EventBus`.

#### What is the difference between interface based callback and passing activity directly?

When you use an interface, you are not tying your Fragment implementation to a particular activity. If you want to re-use that fragment with another activity, you can easily do that.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are used extensively from a reusability point of view. Context of an activity is tied to that activity and the context of one Activity is not same as that of another activity.
To achieve the decoupled state of fragments from activities we user interface callbacks. Now when you want Fragment FragA to be used in A and B, you can add it to B and implement the interface of the Fragment and start receiving callbacks.